# ScalaMock won't mock my TextMessage

Tags: scala, mocking, jms, scalatest, scalamock

I am using ScalaMock3 and I am trying to create a mock of a `javax.jms.TextMessage` within my ScalaTest spec.

```
import javax.jms.TextMessage
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, WordSpecLike}

class MySpec extends WordSpecLike
  with Matchers
  with MockFactory {

  "MySpec" should {
    "create the mock I want!" in {

      val msg = mock[TextMessage]
      msg.getText _ expects() returning "my_text"

      msg.getText shouldBe "my_text"
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I try to compile, I get the following:

```
[error] /my/path/MySpec.scala:14: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.scalamock.util.Defaultable[java.util.Enumeration]  
[error] val msg = mock[TextMessage] 
                      ^
```

Looking online, I found this (unresolved) [issue](https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock/issues/29), but I was hoping someone could suggest a work-around at least...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Basically this happens because of the API differences between Java 1.4 and >= 1.5 versions.

`TextMessage` uses the Java 1.4 non-generic type `java.util.Enumeration` (return type from `getPropertyNames` inherited from `javax.jms.Message`), whereas in newer JVMs `java.util.Enumeration<E>` is a generic class with a type parameter.

When ScalaMock tries to create a mocked instance of this interface, it fails there:

```
null.asInstanceOf[java.util.Enumeration] 
Main.scala:46: trait Enumeration takes type parameters
```

I don't think there's much you can do unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fixed issue for ScalaMock: https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock/issues/29

Add this to your code:

```
implicit val d = new Defaultable[java.util.Enumeration[_]] {
  override val default = null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's not an optimal solution, embedding the offending class in a wrapper class allows for mocking the behavior within your test suite.

```
class TextMessageWrapper {
  lazy val textMessage: TextMessage = ???

  def getMessage() = textMessage.getMessage()
}
```

You can then pass `wrapper.textMessage` wherever an instance of `TextMessage` is required

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
implicit object DefaultableEnumeration extends Defaultable[java.util.Enumeration[Object]] {
    val default = new java.util.Enumeration[Object] {
        override def hasMoreElements: Boolean = false
        override def nextElement: Object = throw new NoSuchElementException("no elements")
    }
```

I did something similar when I got this error with `java.util.List<T>` and the compiler stopped complaining after this.